# Do I have to be an owner of the website in order to create a Google Chrome app for it?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-web-store

I want to create some apps to add to Google Chrome (so they appear as an app in the "new tab" page) that are nothing but a link to websites like Facebook, Stack Overflow, etc.

Can I publish it to the [WebStore](http://chrome.google.com/webstore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Chrome app that points to a domain that is not yours, but you **cannot** add it to the Chrome Store. I followed the [hosted app tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html). If you ***really*** want your app on the Chrome Store and you own a domain, you can have your hosted app manifest.json point to a URL that you own and have that URL do a redirect to the domain that you do not own. If you do not own a domain, you can get one for free from http://www.tk/.

[image: Chrome Store Denial]